# filtering data in pandas where string is in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
team_1  score_1 team_2  score_2
AUS     2       SCO     1
ENG     1       ARG     0
JPN     0       ENG     2
```

I can retreive all the data from a single team by using:
**#list specifiying team of interest**

```
team = ['ENG']
```

**#slice the dataframe to show only the rows where the column 'Team 1' or 'Team 2' value is in the specified string list 'team'**

```
df.loc[df['team_1'].isin(team) | df['team_2'].isin(team)]
```

```
team_1  score_1 team_2  score_2
ENG     1       ARG     0
JPN     0       ENG     2
```

How can I now return only the score for my 'team' such as:

```
team    score
ENG     1
ENG     2
```

Maybe creating an index to each team so as to filter out?
Maybe encoding the team_1 and team_2 columns to filter out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_df_1 = df[df.team_1 =='ENG'][['team_1', 'score_1']]
new_df_1 =new_df_1.rename(columns={"team_1":"team", "score_1":"score"})
#   team  score
#  0  ENG      1
```

```
new_df_2 = df[df.team_2 =='ENG'][['team_2', 'score_2']]
new_df_2 = new_df_2.rename(columns={"team_2":"team", "score_2":"score"})
#  team  score
# 1  ENG      2
```

then concat two dataframe:

```
pd.concat([new_df_1, new_df_2])
```

the output is :

```
 team  score
0  ENG      1
1  ENG      2
```

Comment: Thanks, rather than repeating the two steps, perhaps it would be cleaner to create two loops. Something like...


team_score_dict = {'team_1':'score_1', 'team_2':'score_2'}


`for i in team_score_dict:
    print(i, team_score_dict[i])
    df_team_1 = df[df.team_1 == 'ENG'][[i, team_score_dict[i]]]
    df_team_1 = df_team_1.rename(columns={"team_1":"team", "score_1":"score"})`

but in this instance df_team_1 is being overwritten when the second key is being evaluated. How can i create a dynamic dataframe name?

Answer (score 0):

[Melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) the columns, [filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) for values in team, compute the sum of the scores column, and filter for only teams and score:

```
 team = ["ENG"]

(
    df
    .melt(cols, value_name="team")
    .query("team in @team")
    .assign(score=lambda x: x.filter(like="score").sum(axis=1))
    .loc[:, ["team", "score"]]
)

    team    score
1   ENG        1
5   ENG        2
```